# Self invoking function variants

Tags: javascript

Are these two functions below same ? (See the parenthesis at the end)

```
(function () {
  alert('hi');
}());
```

and

```
(function () {
  alert('hi');
})();
```

Comment: Why not run both of the functions, then compare the results?

Comment: They produce the same result. That's why the confusion.

Comment: This is like a tabs vs. spaces debate... only the way I do it is correct.

Comment: first one is incorrect ( in terms of **best practice** )